# git ignores files unexpectedly

Tags: git, git-svn

I have git repo migrated from svn. There is a problem about git ignoring files unexpectedly.
It ignores ALL `png` files I add to the project, although there is no rule at `.gitignore` file

A little more info (this maybe irrelevant), I used to ignore "some" `png` files when I was working with svn and this is specified in `.gitignore` file. Something like; `/project/web/images/white/.*png` So this should be aplying to one folder right? I don't know if this is anything to do with my problem, since even I remove this line, the problem persists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your .gitignore? also, have you set up a global .gitignore? ala `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange, I deleted the .gitignore file and re-added the same file again. And now it is fixed.